# Dragging the react bootstrap modals using interactjs is facing a issue while dragging for the first time

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, drag-and-drop

Dragging the react bootstrap modals using interactjs is facing a issue while dragging for the first time.

I need to use '.modal-dialog' class as the target selector for dragging using interactjs.
When the modal initailly loads on the page, it has transform applied as transform: translate(-50%, -50%) through css class as follow.

.modal.in .modal-dialog {

```
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transition: none;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

when I try to drag the modal for the first time, the drag is going to the right when I drag to left side(dragging is not smooth). This is probably caused by the fact that the modals already have a transform applied when they first load (left 50% up 50%) and using the mouse offset on the first move doesn’t take this into account when setting the new transform.

How could I resolve this issue on very first drag?